# iFrame: Div not getting displayed

Tags: html, iframe

I have a simple situation as shown below:

```
 <body>
     <iframe id='my_iframe' name='my_iframe' style='display:none;'></iframe>
 <form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_test.php"            target='my_iframe'>
     <input name="theText1" id="theText1" type="text" />
     <input name="theFile1" id="theFile1" type="file" />
     <button style="width:40px;height:10px;" name="button1" id="submit" type="submit" />
 </form>
     <div  style='width:100px;height:100px;' id='target_div'>Test Text</div>
 </body>
```

Problem: The Div is not visible. It does show if I move it above the iframe. I have never used an iframe before. Can't figure this one out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling with JSFiddle (pun intended), it appears that the `button` tag is not self-closing.  Changing `<button ...... />` to `<button ....></button>` seemed to have made the div tag appear correctly ("Test Text" was being placed inside of the button, which makes me conclude that the `button` tag is not self-closing).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5L9Q/2/)